# How do i Create a Zenity form with a check list in it

Tags: 16.04, bash, zenity

I am trying to create a small GUI in Zenity, for it i a few text inputs coupled with a checklist. It seems however the only list i can add to a form is a list of fixed values, and not one with checkboxes in it. Is there any solution to this?

Basically it's something like this, but --checklist isn't available for forms, and i have no idea how else to put these things into the same window.

```
zenity --forms --title="Options"\
--text="Edit options"\
--add-entry="File:"\
--add-entry="Username:"\
--add-list="Features" --checklist\'
```

I tries adding values to the list, and columns, but doing this:

```
zenity --forms --title="Options"\
--text="Edit options"\
--add-entry="File:"\
--add-entry="Username:"\
--add-list="Features" \
--list-values="A|B|C" \
```

That did not help, however, as it just adds 3 strings in the list box. I thought i'd try to make a checklist containing other entries, so first i made a basic checklist.

```
zenity --list --checklist --title="Options"\
--text="Select your features"\
--column="Use"\
--column="Feature"\
TRUE A\
False B\
```

Piece of cake! Then i thought i'd just add an entry, just like in the forms:

```
zenity --list --checklist --title="Options"\
    --text="Select your features"\
    --add-entry="File:"\
    --column="Use"\
    --column="Feature"\
    TRUE A\
    False B\
```

It runs just as it should, but the text entry field is never displayed.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the zenity code with an explanation of what you've tried and what happened instead?

Comment: code samples has been added :)

Comment: Now its a very high quality question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear the `--add-entry` option is not supported when `--list  --checklist` are used. I adapted your code to create:

```
#!/bin/bash

zenity --list --checklist --title="Options"\
    --text="Select your features"\
    --column="Use"\
    --column="Feature"\
    TRUE A\
    False B\

zenity --forms --title="Create user" --text="Add new user" \
   --add-entry="First Name" \
   --add-entry="Last Name" \
   --add-entry="Username" \
   --add-password="Password" \
   --add-password="Confirm Password" \
   --add-calendar="Expires"
```

The first section you know what it looks like already. The second section looks like this:

[image: Zenity Add Entry]

The `--add-entry` works on `--forms` dialog box type but not on `--list` dialog box type.

**Credit for --forms** code to: ([Post on Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103277/how-do-i-create-a-dialog-with-multiple-text-fields-using-zenity))

Comment: Thanks. I eventually realised this and swotched to yad. Lists are still not supported in forms, but there are More elements to work with, particularly the field is very Nice.

Comment: Since posting this answer I too switched to `yad` which is infinitely more powerful.